# Trouble Communicating from Popup Script to Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a Chrome Extension with JavaScript and I am struggling figuring out how I am supposed to communicate between the popup script (the javascript that is linked to the popup HTML) and the content script which has access to the webpage DOM.

Ive looked at the official [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) and have used this example

```js
// popup.js
(async () => {
  const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"});
  // do something with response here, not outside the function
  console.log(response);
})();
```

```js
// script.js 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
        if (request.greeting === "hello")
          sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});   } );
```

Here is my manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Test App"
    },
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab"],
    "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["script.js"]
    }]
}
```

the sendMessage function in the popup.js causes this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

However, when I set up the extension to use a service worker and put the script.js code in there, like so:

```json
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Test App"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab"],
    "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["cs.js"]
    }]
}
```

```js
// background.js 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
        if (request.greeting === "hello")
          sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});   } );
```

I can successfully communicate between the two scripts. The problem though is that service workers do not have access to the DOM, so this is not useful for me.

What am I doing wrong, why can't I communicate between the popup script and the content script?

Comment: When communicating with tab, use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` instead of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

Comment: "Receiving end does not exist" means that the content script is not yet ready to receive (and reply to) the first message.

Comment: For simple tasks use executeScript instead of messaging, [examples](/a/67227376), because you'll have to use it anyway to [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.